# Отображение файлов в консоли linux

Tags: linux, csv, sublime-text, кодировка

У меня есть файл (Допустим csv). Если я открываю его в консоли (cat или less), или в sublime-text, то некоторые поля могут содержать посторонние символы (В sublime вроде `<0x1c>` или `<0x10>`), в консоли - квадратик с цифрами, в виме - `^\` или `^P`

В тоже время, если открть файл в pandas (read_csv) или в libreoffice, то поля выглядят корректно.

Как я понимаю, это проблема с кодировкой, но не могу ее решить.

Что можно сделать для корректного просмотра файла в консоли или других текстовых редакторах?

Comment: это может быть разделить полей. И это объясняет, почему libreoffice умеет - он их парсит. Если это часть текста, то тут нужно смотреть. мне вначале показалось, что 0х10 - это перевод строки, но это не так. В целом, нужно смотреть в реальные данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0x10 - DATA LINK ESCAPE. Означает, что следующий за ним управляющий символ должен восприниматься как данные, а не как управляющий символ.

0x1c - INFORMATION SEPARATOR FOUR - предназначался для разделения полей в базах данных

Скорее всего, проблема не в кодировке, а в том, какая программа писала этот файл.